# ¿Cómo puedo leer y calcular el promedio de cada persona que esta en un archivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Ejemplo de archivo.txt

```
Jose_Lopez quimica 89.00
Jose_Lopez matematicas 85.34
Maria_Martinez fisica 95.50
Maria_Martinez español 90.00
```

***salida esperada***

```
Jose_Lopez 87.17
Maria_Martinez 92.75
```

Mi código es este, pero solo me calcula el promedio general.

```
from statistics import mean

def promedio_archivo(filename : str):
    archivo = open(filename, 'r')
    archivo = archivo.read().split()
    return mean([float(archivo[linea]) for linea in range(2, len(archivo), 3)])
```

Comment: Tu codigo calcula el promedio general por que no sabe a quien le pertenece los datos, para este caso podrías usar un diccionario para almacenar los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario lo puedes hacer almacenando los datos en un diccionario  de esta forma

```
prom_alumnos ={}
def promedio_archivo(filename : str):
    #aqui pones todo como lo tienes
    #cambue esto ya que lo probé en Google colab y no puedo poner archivos 
    archivo = filename.split()
   #separamos la información del estudiante 
    name = archivo[0]
    curso = archivo[1]
    nota = archivo[2]
    #almacenamos en un diccionario 
    if name not in prom_alumnos:
         prom_alumnos[name] = [curso,[float(nota)]]
    else:
         prom_alumnos[name][1].append(float(nota))
    #recirre el diccionario y saca el promedio
    for alum in prom_alumnos:
         prom = prom_alumnos[alum]
         prom =sum( prom[1])/len(prom[1])
         print(f'{alum} con promedio: {prom}')
    #return mean([float(archivo[linea]) for linea in range(2, len(archivo), 3)])
```

**Probamos**

```
# simule la lectura por líneas de la función open()
archivo = ['Jose_Lopez quimica 89.00','Jose_Lopez matematicas 85.34','Maria_Martinez fisica 95.50','Maria_Martinez español 90.00']

for alum in archivo:
     promedio_archivo(alum)
```

Y esto retorna lo esperado.
**Salida**

```
Jose_Lopez con promedio: 87.17
Maria_Martinez con promedio: 92.75
```

**Nota**
Para que funcione deberás cambiar el `read()` por `readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría meterlo en un DF de Pandas. Fijate que especificas que las columnas se separan con una cadena vacia.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('notas.txt', sep=" ",header=None, names= ['Nombre','Asignatura', 'Notas'])
```

Una vez dentro puedes hacer un groupby por nombre y luego aplicarle la media.

```
mean_df = df.groupby("Nombre").mean()
mean_df
```